# CriteriaQuery "where" gets lost when "orderBy" is applied

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am learning how to use CriteriaQuery in JPA 2.0 and hit a snag.  My application builds a query with interactive input from the user.   When the column headers are clicked, an orderBy term is applied.  When they type into a text field right under the column header, a filter is applied to that column.

Doing this, I can use the **orderBy()** method and it works, for any number of terms.   I can use the **where()** method and it works.   When I use both together, the **where()** predicate gets ignored.

If I reverse the order of what gets called to the CriteriaQuery object it makes no difference.  If a sort is applied the filter no longer works.

I have tried looking for examples on the web where both methods are used on the same query but haven't found one.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?  Is there something I missed in the documentation?

This is using Derby via eclipselink 2.2.0.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to construct the query?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone I found the bug.  It was not a problem in the JPA at all -- a subtle problem with an if statement caused the filter terms to be erased when a sort term was introduced.   Let's hear it for test code.

Here was the test code I was going to post.   It works.   Textbook.

```
    CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Location> cq = qb.createQuery(Location.class);        
    Root<Location> root = cq.from(Location.class);

    // test case

    cq.where(qb.like(qb.upper(root.get(Location_.name)), "C%"));
    cq.orderBy(qb.desc(root.get(Location_.id)));
    TypedQuery<Location> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    q.setFirstResult(0);
    q.setMaxResults(20);
    list = q.getResultList();
```